# Простой запрос LEFT JOIN без NULL  для второй таблицы

Tags: mysql

Есть такой запрос, который выводит названия стран, по шаблону LIKE и выводит для каждой страны, список городов, относящихся к этой стране.

```
 SELECT *FROM (`country`)
`LEFT JOIN `citytocountry` ON `citytocountry`.`CountryId` = `country`.`idCountry
`WHERE `CountryNameF` LIKE 'russia%'ORDER BY `CountryName` DESC
```

Проблема в том, что если для страны нет городов, то возвращается NULL для всех не найденных городов по соответствию LIKE. Т-е будет NULL равное найденных записям по условию LIKE.

Comment: `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Не подходит, потому что всегда нужно выводить страны, даже если нет городов

Comment: Кстати, нашел в сети в точности схожий с моим вопрос:
http://www.sql.ru/forum/1058791/vyvod-dannyh-iz-dvuh-svyazannyh-tablic

Comment: По примеру выше, выходит, что так:

SELECT country.CountryName country, GROUP_CONCAT( citytocountry.CityName ) citytocountry
FROM country
LEFT JOIN citytocountry ON country.idCountry = citytocountry.CountryId
LIMIT 0 , 30

Только нужно применить LIKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В T-SQL есть функция IsNull(City,0), которая вернёт указанное значение вместо NULL
Ещё GROUP BY idCountry, City чтобы исключить  все повторы.

Comment: Это более похоже на правду, проверю сейчас

Comment: City - это первичный ключ?

Comment: В общем уточню еще раз задачу: вывести все страны по соответствию LIKE и вывести для каждой страны привязанные к ней города (по ключу связь). Не знаю, возможно ли это сделать одним запросом

Comment: хочется повернуть таблицу ? типа
country,city1,city2,city3 ? это называется pivot table,

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то Вы хотите получить примерно следующее:

    SELECT c.CountryNameF, cc.CityNameF
    FROM ('Country') as c 
    LEFT JOIN 'citytocountry' as cc
    ON (c.CountryID = cc.idCountry) AND (c.CountryNameF LIKE   'russia%')
    GROUP BY c.CountryNameF, cc.CityNameF
    ORDER BY `CountryNameF` DESC

Comment: Совсем не то, к тому же вы с альясами таблиц немного напутали:
Вот Ваш запрос:

SELECT c.CountryName, cc.CityName
FROM country as c 
LEFT JOIN citytocountry as cc
ON (c.idCountry = cc.CountryId) AND (c.CountryName LIKE  'a%')
GROUP BY c.CountryName, cc.CityName
ORDER BY c.CountryName DESC

Он выводит все названия стран и NULL значения города, т-е одна пара: страна - город. А нужно: страна : города

И еще, подскажите пожалуйста, как в комментариях оформлять текст под код, как это сделано у вас?!
tablic

Comment: Чтобы выводить каждый город в каждый отдельный столбец, необходимо сначала выполнить текущий запрос, далее выполнить разворот таблицы как Вам писали выше, PIVOT TABLE.
Код в комментариях, так же как и в тексте: 4 пробела перед текстом. Про это в справке написано.